# error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

when i compile in VS 2003 ent i get these errors

```
C:\SRC\Program\_Interface\FuncTextCmd.cpp(953): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
C:\SRC\Program\_Interface\FuncTextCmd.cpp(958): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
C:\SRC\Program\_Interface\FuncTextCmd.cpp(963): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
C:\SRC\Program\_Interface\FuncTextCmd.cpp(968): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
C:\SRC\Program\_Interface\FuncTextCmd.cpp(973): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
C:\SRC\Program\_Interface\FuncTextCmd.cpp(978): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
C:\SRC\Program\_Interface\FuncTextCmd.cpp(982): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
```

this is this part of FuncTextCmd.cpp it's referring to

```
BOOL TextCmd_CHANGEGLOW( CScanner& scanner )
{//98
#ifdef __WORLDSERVER
CUser* pUser    = (CUser*)scanner.dwValue;
scanner.GetToken();
CString strcr = scanner.Token;
CString CHANGEGLOW;


if( 2 <= strcr.GetLength() && strcr.GetLength() <= 7)
{
strcr.MakeLower();

if( strcmp( strcr, "RED" ) == 0 )
{
CHANGEGLOW = 1;//line 953
}
else
if( strcmp( strcr, "BLUE" ) == 0 )
{
CHANGEGLOW = 2;//line 958
}
else
if( strcmp( strcr, "GREEN" ) == 0 )
{
CHANGEGLOW = 3;//line 963
}
else
if( strcmp( strcr, "YELLOW" ) == 0 )
{
CHANGEGLOW = 4;//line 968
}
else
if( strcmp( strcr, "ORANGE" ) == 0 )
{
CHANGEGLOW = 5;//line 973
}
else
if( strcmp( strcr, "PINK" ) == 0 )
{
CHANGEGLOW = 6;//line 978
}
else if( strcmp( strcr, "PURPLE" ) == 0 )
{
CHANGEGLOW = 7;//line 982
}
else
{
strcr += "unknown glow";
pUser->AddText( strcr );
return FALSE;
}
}
else
{
strcr += "unknown glow";
pUser->AddText( strcr );
return FALSE;

}//2

#endif // __WORLDSERVER
return TRUE;
}
```

this is for a game by the way it's in c++

the part above is saying if the user types said colors in the chat box then the glow around their body will change to what they typed but this is only the command the main part of this feature is handled in Mover.cpp of my source then part for glow can be seen below

```
void CMover::CreateAbilityOption_SetItemSFX( int nAbilityOption )
{
extern DWORD CHANGEGLOW;
DWORD dwSfx = 0;

switch( nAbilityOption )
{
case 3: dwSfx = XI_GEN_ITEM_SETITEM03; break;
case 4: dwSfx = XI_GEN_ITEM_SETITEM04; break;
case 5: dwSfx = XI_GEN_ITEM_SETITEM05; break;
case 6: dwSfx = XI_GEN_ITEM_SETITEM06; break;
case 7: dwSfx = XI_GEN_ITEM_SETITEM07; break;
case 8: dwSfx = XI_GEN_ITEM_SETITEM08; break;
case 9: dwSfx = XI_GEN_ITEM_SETITEM09; break;
case 10: dwSfx = CHANGEGLOW; break;
}

switch( CHANGEGLOW )
{
case 1: dwSfx = RED; break; //make sure that the uppercase RED is what
//you defined in defineobj.h
case 2: dwSfx = BLUE; break; //make sure that the uppercase BLUE is what
// you defined //in defineobj.h
case 3: dwSfx = GREEN; break; //make sure that the uppercase GREEN is what you
//defined in defineobj.h
case 4: dwSfx = YELLOW; break; //make sure that the uppercase YELLOW is what you
//defined in defineobj.h
case 5: dwSfx = ORANGE; break; //make sure that the uppercase ORANGE is what you
//defined in defineobj.h
case 6: dwSfx = PINK; break; //make sure that the uppercase PINK is what you
//defined in defineobj.h
case 7: dwSfx = PURPLE; break; //make sure that the uppercase PURPLE is what you
//defined in defineobj.h
}

//else 
//case 10: dwSfx = XI_GEN_ITEM_SETITEM10; break;


CSfxPartsLinkShoulder* pSfx = NULL;
D3DXVECTOR3 v3Scal = D3DXVECTOR3( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );


if( nAbilityOption == 3 )
{
    // ¾î±ú
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 0;
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 1;
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
}
/*
else
if( nAbilityOption == 4 )
{
    // ¸öÅë
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 6;
    pSfx->SetScale(D3DXVECTOR3( 2.2f, 2.2f, 2.2f ));
}
*/
else
if( nAbilityOption == 4 )
{
    // ¸öÅë
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 6;
    pSfx->SetScale(D3DXVECTOR3( 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f ));
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
}
else
if( nAbilityOption == 5 )
{
    // ¾î±ú
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 0;
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 1;
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ¾î±ú, ÆÈ¸ñ Áß°£
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 4;     
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 5; 
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
}
else
if( nAbilityOption == 6 )
{
    // ¾î±ú
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 0;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 1;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ¾î±ú, ÆÈ¸ñ Áß°£
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 4;     
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 5; 
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ÆÈ¸ñ
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 2;
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 3;     
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
}
else
if( nAbilityOption == 7 )
{
    // ¾î±ú
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 0;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 1;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ¾î±ú, ÆÈ¸ñ Áß°£
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 4;     
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 5; 
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ÆÈ¸ñ
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 2;
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 3;     
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ¼Õ   
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 8;         
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 9;     
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
}
else
if( nAbilityOption == 8 )
{
    // ¾î±ú
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 0;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 1;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ¾î±ú, ÆÈ¸ñ Áß°£
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 4;     
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 5; 
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ÆÈ¸ñ
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 2;
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 3;     
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ¼Õ   
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 8;         
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 9;     
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;

    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, XI_SETIEM_EFFECTHAND, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 9;         
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.2f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
}
else
if( nAbilityOption == 9 )
{
    // ¾î±ú
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 0;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 1;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ¾î±ú, ÆÈ¸ñ Áß°£
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 4;     
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 5; 
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ÆÈ¸ñ
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 2;
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 3;     
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ¼Õ   
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 8;         
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 9;     
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ¹ß
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 26;    
    pSfx->SetScale(D3DXVECTOR3( 1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f ));        
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 29;
    pSfx->SetScale(D3DXVECTOR3( 1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f ));
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;


    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, XI_SETIEM_EFFECTHAND, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 9;         
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.2f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
}
else
if( nAbilityOption == 10 )
{
    // ¾î±ú
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 0;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 1;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ¾î±ú, ÆÈ¸ñ Áß°£
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 4;     
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 5; 
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ¸öÅë
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 6;
    pSfx->SetScale(D3DXVECTOR3( 3.0f, 4.5f, 3.0f ));
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 7;     
    pSfx->SetScale(D3DXVECTOR3( 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f ));        
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ¼Õ   
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 8;         
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 9; 
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.1f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ÆÈ¸ñ
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 2;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 3;     
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    // ¹ß
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 26;            
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, dwSfx, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 29;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;


    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, XI_SETIEM_EFFECTHAND, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 8;         
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.2f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
    pSfx = (CSfxPartsLinkShoulder*)CreateSfx( D3DDEVICE, XI_SETIEM_EFFECTHAND, GetPos(), GetId(), GetPos(), GetId(), -1 );
    pSfx->m_nPartsLink = 9;         
    pSfx->m_v3Offset.y = 0.2f;
    pSfx->m_nOldAbilityOption = nAbilityOption;
}
}

#endif //__CLIENT
```

Comment: You're trying to assign an integer to a `CString`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first code snippet, you defined `CHANGEGLOW` to be a `CString`, and then you assign a number. It is no surprise that this doesn't work. Given that in the second snippet you declared it as `DWORD` I guess that's what you actually wanted. So the fix probably is to just change `CString` to `DWORD` in that definition. Actually, probably `extern DWORD` because otherwise it's a local variable to the function and assigning it won't have any lasting effect.

Actually I wonder why you locally declare it anyway. Since you cannot reuse the identifier globally, and have to define it somewhere globally anyway, is there any reason not to have a global declaration at the beginning of the file (or, better, in some header file)?

Comment: indeed I change it to extern and compiled without errors thanks By The Way does anyone see how they might improve the code post if you can

Comment: @420Twisted1: One thing I notice just now is that you call `MakeLower` on `strcr`, but then compare it to all-uppercase strings. I'm pretty sure it will never match a single one ...

Comment: @420Twisted1: Another thing: Given that the switch on CHANGEGLOW is on consecutive numbers, I think using an array and indexing it would be better (i.e. `DWORD colors = { RED, BLUE, GREEN, ... };` and then instead of the switch (after an appropriate range test, of course) just `dwFsx = colors[CHANGEGLOW-1];`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign numeric literals (1, 2, 3 etc) to a variable of type `CString`. Even if that compiled, it would seem like a bad idea to me. Perhaps you want a different variable type, e.g. `int`? Given that you're later going to `switch` on the value of it, it looks like you want some sort of numeric type, anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Your type is wrong in `FuncTextCmd.cpp`. You have

```
CString CHANGEGLOW;
```

when it should be

```
DWORD CHANGEGLOW;
```